# Visual C++ Error: LNK2019, LNK2028 and LNK1120

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, java-native-interface, lnk2019

I'm working on a basic application to create a Java VM and launch a Java program from C++ with JNI. However, I have some compiling errors:

```
Error   6   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000D) "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __clrcall JarLauncher::launchJar(void)" (?launchJar@JarLauncher@@$$FQ$AAM_NXZ)  
Error   5   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00000C) "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void *)" (?JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs@@$$J14YGJPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __clrcall JarLauncher::launchJar(void)" (?launchJar@JarLauncher@@$$FQ$AAM_NXZ)      
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs(void *)" (?JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs@@$$J14YGJPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __clrcall JarLauncher::launchJar(void)" (?launchJar@JarLauncher@@$$FQ$AAM_NXZ)   
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" long __stdcall JNI_CreateJavaVM(struct JavaVM_ * *,void * *,void *)" (?JNI_CreateJavaVM@@$$J212YGJPAPAUJavaVM_@@PAPAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __clrcall JarLauncher::launchJar(void)" (?launchJar@JarLauncher@@$$FQ$AAM_NXZ)   
Error   9   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Any help?

Comment: Those are linker errors, not compiler errors. It's telling you you're missing some symbols.  You either need to to provide implementations or get them for a library.

Comment: Seems you did forget to link the library where those two functions reisde.

Comment: The JDK provides two .lib files which are both attached to the linker. I've attached jvm.lib and jawt.lib (even though I probably don't need the latter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didn't link **jvm.lib**. You usually find it in `%ProgramFiles%\Java\jdk1.X.XX_XX\lib`, then you can add it to your linker input settings.

Also, you'll need to load **jvm.dll** at runtime (and add it to the delay loaded dlls). On Windows, you can get the current location from the registry. Query `SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion` for the current runtime version and `SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\<version>\RuntimeLib` for the path of jvm.dll.

Using those paths you can also check if the required runtime version is present on the system.

Comment: The path is apparently C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll, but the directory C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client doesn't exist...

Comment: @Klayderpus That is weird, are you sure java is installed correctly? On my system it's exactly in that location.

Comment: I'll do a a fresh install of the JRE and JDK in the morning...it's currently 3am and I need some sleep. Thanks for the help.